# Prove indefinite integral is continuous

Tags: integration, continuity, indefinite-integrals

I have the proof from my prof and i understand most of the steps separately but i can't completely comprehend the end. The prof doesn't really explain the steps i would be really happy if someone can summarize it.

$f\epsilon R[a,b] F:= \int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ is indefinite integral of f. Proove F is continuous on [a,b]

$F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f = \int_{a}^{w}f + \int_{w}^{x}f = F(w) + \int_{w}^{x}f \Rightarrow F(x)-F(w)=\int_{w}^{x}f \text{ Now, if } \left | f(x) \right | \leq M \text{ on }n [a,b] -M(x-w)\leq \int_{w}^{x}f\leq M(x-w) \Rightarrow \left | F(x)-F(w) \right |\leq \left | \int_{w}^{x}f \right |\leq M\left | x-w \right | $ as $x\rightarrow w, F(x)\rightarrow F(w)$

Comment: The idea is that as $x$ gets very close to $w$, $F(x)$ gets very close to $F(w)$. The bound $|F(x)-F(w)|\leq M|x-w|$ means that $F(x)$ and $F(w)$ get *squished* together as $x$ and $w$ get squished together. This is the fundamental concept behind continuity. Phrased differently, a very small change in the input of $F$ results in a very small change in the output of $F$.

Comment: thank you, that was very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain the proof in more detail below:

Consider any number $c\in(a,b)$ (the endpoints are considered separately). The definition of $F$ implies that $F(c)=\int_{a}^{c}f(t)dt$, so using standard properties of integrals, we deduce that for $x\neq c$

\begin{align*}
F(x)-F(c) &= \int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt-\int_{a}^{c}f(t)dt\\
&= \int_{c}^{x}f(t)dt
\end{align*}

$f$ was assumed to be Riemann integrable, so it must be bounded. This means that there is a number $M$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Using the integral inequality $|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx|\leq\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx$, we deduce that

\begin{align*}
|F(x)-F(c)| &= \left|\int_{c}^{x}f(t)dt\right|\\
&\leq \int_{c}^{x}|f(x)|dx\\
&\leq \int_{c}^{x}Mdx\\
&= M|x-c|
\end{align*}

The absolute value brackets around $x-c$ are there to compensate for the possibility that $x<c$.

Thus, we have that $|F(x)-F(c)|\leq M|x-c|$. Letting $x\to c$ and applying the squeeze theorem immediately gives $\lim_{x\to c}F(x)=F(c)$, which is what we wanted.

To prove continuity at the endpoints, the same argument applies, the only difference being that we use left and right hand limits for $a$ and $b$, respectively. Thus, $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

The bound $|F(x)-F(c)|\leq M|x-c|$ actually implies that $F$ is Lipschitz continuous, which is stronger than ordinary continuity.

Comment: it was very clear, thank you so much!!