# Lebesgue measurable function and set, $\forall t\in (0,1), $there exists $ E_t \subset E$ such that $\int_{E_t} f(x) dx = t \int_{E} f(x) dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

The question is: Let f be Lebesgue measurable on $R$ and $E\subset R$ be measurable so that $0<A=\int _E f(x)dx < \infty$. Show that for every $t\in (0,1)$ there exists a measurable set $E_t \subset E$ so that $\int_{E_t} f(x) dx = t A$.

My thoughts to solve this question and my question is in step 3:

1. Since $f$ is Lebesgue measurable on $R$, so $f$ can be approximated by simple functions. So if I can show the result is true for $f(x) = \chi _{B}(x)$ where $\chi _{B}(x)$ is a simple function. Then the result is true for Lebesgue measurable $f$.
2. Now $\int _{E} \chi _{B}(x) dx = m(E\cap B)= A$ ($m$ is Lebesgue measure). Now I have to show that there exists a measurable set $E_t \subset E$ such that $m(E_t\cap B)=t \cdot m(E\cap B)= tA$.
3. To show that $m(E_t\cap B)=t \cdot m(E\cap B)= tA$, here is the trouble for me if the above steps are correct. After searching posts here, I think I can define a $g(x) = m(E\cap B\cap (-\infty, x))$. I need to show $g(x)$ is continuous and then that could lead to the conclusion that there will be $t_0$ such that $0<g(t_0) = t \cdot m(E\cap B)<m(E\cap B)$.

I would like to hear about your comments about the above steps and see if there is any error. Thanks!

Comment: Your last sentence in step 1 is unproved, and useless. Hint: $s\mapsto\int_0^sf(x)dx$ is continuous.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for your hint. I just wonder would $s\mapsto\int_{(-\infty, s)\cap E}f(x)dx$ work since I want to find the subset of $E$.

Comment: Oh yes, wlog $f=0$ outside $E.$ And I wrongly typed $0$ instead of $-\infty.$ Btw, the continuity in my first comment is a standard result, [quite easy to prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4072310/386889). But you wrote "$f$ measurable" instead of "$f$ integrable".

Comment: As a general rule, it's advisable not to accept an answer less than an hour after posting the question, as it possibly discourages others from posting an answer. Allow at least a day or two.

Comment: @KCd First day here. I have undo the accept and will wait for 2 days. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Note however that answers are very often accepted within a few hours, if not minutes, but that you can always change your mind and unaccept an answer to accept another one.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, $f$ is measurable and I think this is a trouble here because it won't be the same as $\int _E |f(x)| dx <\infty$. I'm still working on this.

Comment: For the Lebesgue integral $\int_Ef$ to be defined and finite, $f$ has to be integrable. The only non integrable functions for which the integral is defined are the measurable functions with constant sign and infinite integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your statement to make sense, $f$ must be assumed to be not only measurable but integrable (but $f$ is not necessarily of constant sign, and its integral $A\in\Bbb R$ does not need to be $>0$). Assume moreover wlog that $f$ is $0$ outside $E.$

Your last sentence in step 1 is unproved, and useless. Instead, consider the function
$$g:s\mapsto\int_{-\infty}^sf(x)\,dx.$$
The continuity of $g$ is a standard result, [quite easy to prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4072282/prove-indefinite-integral-is-continuous/4072310#4072310).

Since $\lim_{-\infty}g=0$ and $\lim_{+\infty}g=A,$ by the intermediate value theorem
$$\forall t\in(0,1)\quad\exists s\in\Bbb R\quad g(s)=tA,$$
and $E_t:=(-\infty,s)\cap E$ is then a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Since your $f$ can take both positive and negative values on $E$, I'll break up the solution to two steps.

Step 1: Reduce to the case where $f$ on its domain of integration is a nonnegative measurable function.

On $E$, let $f^+ = \max(0,f)$ and $f^- = \max(0,-f)$, so $f^+$ and $f^-$ are positive on disjoint measurable subsets $E^{+}$ and $E^{-}$ of $E$, with $f = f^+ - f^{-}$ on $E$.  Then
$$
\int_E f(x)\,dx = \int_{E} f^+(x)\,dx - \int_{E} f^{-}(x)\,dx = \int_{E^{+}} f^+(x)\,dx - \int_{E^{-}} f^{-}(x)\,dx.
$$
Suppose your result can be shown when the Lebesgue measurable functions being integrated are nonnegative.  Then apply this to $f^+$ on $E^+$ and $f^-$ on $E^-$: for $t \in (0,1)$ there are measurable subsets $E^+_t \subset E^+$ and $E^{-}_t \subset E^{-}$ such that $$
\int_{E^+_t}f^+(x)\,dx = t\int_{E^+} f^+(x)\,dx = t\int_{E^+} f(x)\,dx, \ \ \ 
\int_{E^{-}_t}f^-(x)\,dx = t\int_{E^-} f^-(x)\,dx = t\int_{E^-} (-f(x))\,dx.
$$
Since $E^+_t$ and $E^{-}_t$ are inside the disjoint subsets $E^+$ and $E^{-}$,
$$
\int_{E^+_t \cup E^{-}_t} f(x)\,dx = \int_{E^+_t} f(x)\,dx + \int_{E^{-}_t} f(x)\,dx = \int_{E^+_t} f^+(x)\,dx - \int_{E^{-}_t} f^{-}(x)\,dx
$$
and
$$
\int_{E^+_t} f^+(x)\,dx - \int_{E^{-}_t} f^{-}(x)\,dx = t\int_{E^+} f(x)\,dx + t\int_{E^-} f(x)\,dx = t\int_E f(x)\,dx, 
$$
so you can use for $E_t$ the subset $E_t^+ \cup E_t^{-}$.

Step 2: Prove the case where $f \geq 0$ on a domain of integration $E$.

The condition $\int_E f(x)\,dx < \infty$ makes integration of $f$ on measurable subsets of $E$ a finite measure, say $\nu$: define $\nu(A) := \int_A f(x)\,dx$ for measurable subsets $A$ in $E$.
Moreover, $\nu$ is nonatomic.

Now we can appeal to the following general theorem about values of finite nonatomic measures.

**Theorem**.  *Let $(X,\nu)$ be a finite nonatomic measure space. For each $t$ in $[0,\nu(X)]$, there is a measurable subset $X_t \subset X$ such that $\nu(X_t) = t$*.

*Proof*. See Theorem 4.2 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/lpspace.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your step 1, I'm afraid I'm not clear on how the general version of this result would follow from proving this result for simple functions. It's true that for any measurable $f$, there exists a sequence of simple functions $s_n$ that converge to $f$ pointwise. However, an $E_t$ that "works" for one $s_n$ might not "work" for another $s_n$...

Your idea for step 3, however, is very nice. We can take that idea and apply it to the general case, not just to the special case where the function is simple.

Concretely, the idea is to consider the function $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by
$$ g(x) := \int_{E \cap (-\infty, x)} f(u) du. $$
You want to prove that:

- $g$ is continuous at all $x \in \mathbb R$.
- $\lim_{x \to -\infty} g(x) = 0$
- $\lim_{x \to +\infty} g(x) = A$.

To prove this, I suggest you use the sequential definition of continuity and limits. That is, I suggest you prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = l \ \  \implies \ \ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E \cap (-\infty, x_n)} f(u) du = \int_{E \cap (-\infty, l)} f(u) du.$$
(Here, $l$ could be in $\mathbb R$, or $l$ could be $-\infty$ or $+\infty$.)
The Dominated Convergence Theorem should get you most of the way there - think about the pointwise limit of the sequence of functions $f \mathbf 1_{E \cap (-\infty, x_n)}$, and bear in mind that this sequence is dominated by the positive integrable function $|f| \mathbf 1_E$.

Finally, having done all this work, you should be able to obtain your result by applying the intermediate value theorem to $g$.

Comment: Thanks Kenny! Now I see why my step 1 isn't quite working. Originally I was considering to use the linearity of simple functions but now I realize this won't work. For the $f \mathbf 1_{E \cap (-\infty, x_n)}$ dominated by $|f| \mathbf 1_E$, I believe I still need to show that $\int _E |f(x)| dx <\infty$ so that we can apply DTC.

Comment: @Thmyem That's a great question. When you write $\int_E f(u) du = A$, it is implicit that $\int_E f^+(u) du$ and $\int_E f^-(u) du$ are both _finite_, and $\int_E f^+(u) du - \int_E f^-(u) du = A$. But then, $\int_E |f(u)| du = \int_E f^+(u) du + \int_E f^-(u) du$ is finite too. (As a general rule, $f$ is integrable if and only if $|f|$ is integrable.)

Comment: Also, there's a second thing you have to be super careful about with regards to DTC. The pointwise limit of $f\mathbf 1_{E \cap (-\infty, x_n)}$ is guaranteed to exist for $u \neq l$, but it might not exist at $u = l$. Fortunately, the singleton set $\{ l \}$ is a null set, so this doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: Thanks for your additional comments about DTC. About the statement $\int_E f(u) du = A< \infty$ implies that $\int_E f^+(u) du$ and $\int_E f^-(u) du$ are both finite, I believe this will be the way to explain Anne Bauval's concern about the integrability of $f$. But I didn't find any formal proof about this point in Folland's book yesterday, do you have any reference about this?

Comment: That's _definitely_ the way to address Anne's point. Regarding the formal proof, this is so closely tied to the definition of an integral that it's just something you should know.

Comment: I don't own Folland's book, so I'm not in a position to comment. However, this logic is pretty clearly set out in Rudin's book in Chapter 1, in the section called Integration of Complex Functions.

Comment: Actually, here's another way to understand this. Suppose that $\int_E f^+(u)du = \infty$ and $\int_E f^-(u) du = -12345$. Then what is $\int_E f(u) du$? Rudin's book would say that $\int_E f(u) du$ is undefined, though coming to think about it, I can see that it is plausible that another book might say that $\int_E f(u) du = \infty$, since $\infty - 12345 = \infty$. However, no reasonable person would say that $\int_E f(u)du$ is a finite number $A$ - that would be ridiculous!

Comment: Okay, and what if $\int_E f^+(u) du = \infty$ and $\int_E f^-(u)du = -\infty$. What is $\int_E f(u)du$ this time? Well, you'd have to say that $\int_E f(u) du$ is undefined, because there is no reasonable value you can assign to $\infty - \infty$.

Comment: So the _only_ way that $\int_E f(u) du$ can be equal to a finite number $A$ is if $\int_E f^+(u) du$ and $\int_E f^-(u) du$ are both finite. (This is assuming that the definitions in your book aren't totally crazy.)